# True as default desired return in if statement

Tags: python

I feel like the True needs to be defined as a desired result somehow because that's how I've used boolean with if statements in the past lessons.

Example:

```
if month == 2 and blablabla == True:
```

But when I see:

```
if month == 2 and is_leap(year)   # ← The function here is returning true
```

I interpret it as:

```
if month ==2 and (is_leap is returning True or False)
```

The lack of True being specified as the desired result doesn't make sense for me.  Is True the default desired result?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `if is_leap(year)` should be interpreted as `if is_leap(year) == True:` (neither `False` nor `None`). You can check [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. `if some_expression` checks the value of `some_expression` and if that evaluates to `True` then the code specified in the block runs. `month == 2 and is_leap(year)` is an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False` if both sub-expressions (`month == 2` and `is_leap(year)`) are both `True`, or they aren't, respectively.

Comment: "The lack of True being specified as the desired result doesn't make sense for me." - Suppose I were to say: "if it is raining, I will take an umbrella with me". Would you **be confused because I did not say** "if it is true that it is raining, I will take an umbrella with me"? If not, then why do you have that exact confusion when reading code?

Comment: @morwyn It's not that "true is the default" - think of everything as boolean expressions. At the end of the day, an if-statement with a boolean expression like `if month == 2 and is_leap(year):` will have to be evaluated in terms of truthy or falsey operands. So, if `month == 2`, and `is_leap(year)` returns true (or something truthy), then the expression will be evaluated as `if true and true:`, which will further be evaluated as just `if true:`. If `is_leap(year)` returned false (or something falsey), it would be evaluated as `if true and false:`, or just `if false:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're asking, but here's what I think can help.
Imagine a single statement:

```
if month == 2:
    proceed
```

the "month == 2" part is assessing the logic in place, and returning "True". So you are saying

```
if True:
    proceed
```

Great! You can add as many conditions to that as you wish, and so long as all of them are True (in your example it reads "if True and True"), it will go into that if block. In your case, is_leap(year) is returning "True" or "False" based on how you defined it. If it returns False, this section of the if block will not run.

Comment: So the part of the solution code in this assignment that I didn't understand was ... if 
month == 2 and is_leap(year):
    return 29 ...
The instructor said that it means if month ==2 and the return from is_leap is true.
I don't understand how True is the defined desired result.

Comment: You want your block to assess that the month is February, and that it is a leap year. Your is_leap function checks if it is a leap year, and if it is, that function returns True. So, if it is February (month == 2) and if it is a leap year (is_leap returns True), then 29 should be returned.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry. I'm still learning how to format code in comments

Comment: My question was more about trying to understand why the default desired result in that if statement was True even though I didn't specifically define it as True. Is this always the default? I'm just used to having to specify True in an if statement. I'm confused why I didn't have to this time

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, "month == 2" returns True or False, but consider what you're actually saying: The Month Is February. That is True. So yes, the if statement has a default of expecting True. If you wanted to expect False, the if statement would run "month != 2", which checks if the month is NOT February, and this would therefore return True for every month but February. tl;dr: your delineation in the default desired outcome being True for an if statement is correct.

Comment: @Morwyn Think that you don't have to say every time that `if (month == 2) == True`, because the `if` will execute if `month == 2` is equal to true anyway. In the same reasoning, you don't have to say `is_leap(year) == True` because the `if` will execute if `is_leap(year)` is equal to true.